# Unable to establish SSL connection with wget

Tags: curl

I am trying to execute :

```
wget https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD
```

I replaced wget 1.12 with 1.16 on my centos machine.

I have set `check-certificate` option to `off` in

```
vi /etc/wgetrc
```

I can infact use `https` usually with wget

```
wget https://google.com
```

It doesn't give ssl error with google.com.

Infact I can access the link on browser just fine. Why does it seem to fail with wget then?

With this command, I get:

```
[root@warehouse ~]# wget 'https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD'
[2] 1487
[3] 1488
[4] 1489
[3]   Done                    reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites
[root@warehouse ~]# --2016-10-06 18:27:48--  https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK
Resolving app.adroll.com (app.adroll.com)... 52.11.56.178, 52.89.249.63
Connecting to app.adroll.com (app.adroll.com)|52.11.56.178|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Edit: Tried with single and double quotes as well.Made no difference:

```
[root@warehouse ~]# wget 'https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD'
--2016-10-06 18:32:38--  https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD
Resolving app.adroll.com (app.adroll.com)... 52.89.249.63, 52.11.56.178
Connecting to app.adroll.com (app.adroll.com)|52.89.249.63|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Edit2: Tried with --no-check-certificate as well:

```
[root@warehouse ~]# wget --no-check-certificate "https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD"
--2016-10-06 18:35:23--  https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD
Resolving app.adroll.com (app.adroll.com)... 52.11.56.178, 52.89.249.63
Connecting to app.adroll.com (app.adroll.com)|52.11.56.178|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Edit 3:

```
using  curl -v "https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?a‌​dvertisable=T4ZPAGYE‌​SJEZZMCCBVEMHK&repor‌​ts=AllCampaignsSumma‌​ry,AllCampaignsChart‌​,AllAds,AllCampaigns‌​Sites&format=csv&cur‌​rency=USD" 
* About to connect() to app.adroll.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 52.11.56.178... connected
* Connected to app.adroll.com (52.11.56.178) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5938
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

Comment: Put the whole URL in single quotes.  The `&` character is meaningful to the shell and is being interpreted.

Comment: You really should use `curl "https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD" > result.html` here

Comment: @Flup: Tried with single quotes as well. still the same

Comment: Try adding `--no-check-certificate` after the `wget` (in case `/etc/wgetrc` isn't being read).  If it doesn't work, please paste the output in your question.

Comment: @Anubioz: gives ssl connect error: curl "https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?a‌​dvertisable=T4ZPAGYE‌​SJEZZMCCBVEMHK&repor‌​ts=AllCampaignsSumma‌​ry,AllCampaignsChart‌​,AllAds,AllCampaigns‌​Sites&format=csv&cur‌​rency=USD" 
curl: (35) SSL connect error

Comment: @Flup: Did. Still the same

Comment: @gags, try `curl -v` to display the actual problem. It seems like a server issue to me, since I'm getting a timeout when trying to connect to `https://app.adroll.com/`...

Comment: @Anubioz: Did. Please check the update

Comment: @gags, I just checked - they block hosting IP ranges (i.e. hetzner), you can't do anything about it.

Comment: I have no problem accessing the host, although: `dig app.adroll.com` shows a round robin DNS record (half your requests might be executed on a different server from the other half) and I get an "ERROR 500: Internal Server Error" --> maybe they're doing maintenance or experiencing problems?

Comment: Using the -d switch on wget will print debug information. My suspicion is that you're able to access the URL through a browser on a different machine than the one you're using, or that wget isn't using the same security settings as your browser for some reason or another. Using the debug option should show you details of the SSL handshake (including whether or not it's actually checking the certificate).

Comment: You say you have wget 1.16 but do you have 1.16.1 or better? That server demands TLS1.1 or better and disconnects for TLS1.0 or SSL3, consistent with your symptom, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237778/wget-tls-1-2-error says TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 were added at 1.16.1 .

Comment: @Anubioz: Block hosting IP ranges?What does that exactly mean? I am sorry I didn't exactly understand why would they block some IP address range?

Comment: To deal with spambots that click advertisments, obviously. http://davebuesing.com/google-analytics-spam-traffic-bots/

Comment: @Anubioz: Thanks. I just tried to wget through my local system. It works. Infact I started getting SSL problem only after installing wget 1.16 . Could you please let me know how do I uninstall this version?

Comment: @Anubioz: Also, using --content-on-error option, it downloads an error page and not the file attachment that it should. Any idea how I could actually download the content?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the server, as seen by the line `* Connected to app.adroll.com (52.11.56.178) port 443 (#0)`  (that excludes firewall and/or routing issues) but then the connection gets severed, as indicated by the NSS error code `* NSS error -5938 * Closing connection #0` and `curl: (35) SSL connect error`.

Typically you would need to see the server-side log to know the exact reason, but @Anubioz seems to have the right idea, the server blocks your connect attempt.

You may be running afoul of their  [invalid traffic](https://help.adroll.com/hc/en-us/articles/212675807-Protection-Against-Invalid-Traffic) protections if you connect from certain IP-address ranges.

> *"Any domains identified as sources of invalid traffic are permanently blocked."*